# Adding values to an object javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have this object:

```
var tableData = [
    { value1: 1, value2: "Something", value3: 10 },
    { value1: 2, value2: "Something else", value3: 12 }
];
```

and I have 3 inputs, when I click button add I want to add input fileds to this object to look like this:

```
var tableData = [
    { value1: 1, value2: "Something", value3: 10 },
    { value1: 2, value2: "Something else", value3: 12 }
    { value1: 3, value2: "Something new else", value3: 5 } // new input
];
```

I know that I have to do something with:

```
buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
    // something here
});
```

Html:

```
<input id="value1" type="text">
<input id="value2" type="text">
<input id="value3" type="text">
<button id="add" type="button">Add</button>

<div>
    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             th>value1</th>
             <th>value2</th>
             <th>value3</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody id="tableData">

       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your HTML with us.

Comment: It is absolutely not clear where those object values should come from. Would you elaborate your question a bit?

Comment: they should come from inputs, I just updated question and put html, so when button add is pressed object should contain value1, value2, value3 from inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tableData` isn't an object, it's an array (which I suppose is also an object, but not in the sense you're thinking of). Adding anything to it is as simple as using `push`.

```js
buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
    tableData.push( {'value1': 3, 'value2': "Something new else", 'value3': 5} );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Array Push** you can achieve it

```
 buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var tableData = [
            { value1: 1, value2: "Something", value3: 10 },
            { value1: 2, value2: "Something else", value3: 12 }
        ];

        tableDataObject={ value1: 3, value2: "Something new else", value3: 5 }
        tableData.push(tableDataObject);

        console.log(tableData);

    }
```